# Passing a multidimentional array through AJAX to Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I created an array:

```
var p = Array();
var obj = {};
obj.resId = RequestData.Table[i].shID;
obj.nesId = RequestData.Table[i].bkid;
obj.BlockRequest = req;
obj.BlockApprove = 0;
obj.MarketingID = i;
obj.UserID = i;
obj.Notes = "";
obj.Operation = "test";
p.push(obj);
```

and tried to send it to a Web API controller through AJAX:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: "testcontroller/testfunction",
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(p),
    dataType: 'json',
    accepts: {
        json: "application/json"
    },
    success: function (response) {

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //debugger;
        alert('failure');
    },
    complete: function () {
    }
});
```

My controller looks like this:

```
<HttpGet()>
Public Function testfunction(ByVal p As List(Of dataclass)) As DataSet
End Function
```

I am not able to access the data in controller in the Web API (in array `p`). Any ideas?

Comment: What does your controller look like? What is `testfunction` expecting? What response are you getting? Also, that's not a multidimensional array, it's an array with an object in it.

Comment: i created a class and tried tyo access the array data inside it.But i am not getting any data inside it

Comment: What does `dataclass` look like? Also, try adding `contentType: "application/json"` to your ajax request.

Comment: use fiddler to capture you post